# generating a dynamic table for questions and answers from firestore on ionic 4 using angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, datatable, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

i have a list of questionnaires with questions associated to the by and id and answers of those questions. i need to display a table for each questionnaire so that the questions will be columns and answers will populate the rows and cells dynamically.

i tried many ways using ng-datatables, angular material tables, normal html table are the only ones displaying something which are not exactly what i want. they display columns data vertically

this is in html

```
  <ion-title> {{questionary.title | uppercase}}</ion-title><br>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col sizeLg="12"  sizeMd="12" sizeSm="12" sizeXs="12">
      <table class="table table-stripped" border="1" >
        <thead>
          <th *ngFor="let question of getQuestions(questionary.id)" color="primary" class="ion-padding" style="white-space: nowrap;">
           {{ question.question.question_title }}
           </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let answe of getQAnswers(questionary.id)" style="border: 1px solid black;">

          <td *ngFor="let answer of getAnswers(answe.question_id); let ii = index"  style="text-align: center;">
                {{answer}}
              </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-card>
```

this is in .ts page class

```
  surveyid: any;
  survey;
  questionarys: Questionnarys[] = [];
  agents: Agents[] = []; questions: Questions[] = []; inputs: InputTypes[] = [];
  answers: Array<Answers> = [];
  questionsArray: Array<Questions> = [];
  questionFullArray: Array<QuestionFull> = [];
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private routa: Router,
              private modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private surveyService: SurveysService,
              private agentsService: AgentsService,
              private questionarysService: QuestionnarysService,
              private questionsServeice: QuestionsService,
              private inputService: InputTypesService,
              private answerService: AnswersService) {
    if (! this.survey) {
      this.survey = {};
    }
    let id;
    id = this.router.snapshot.params.surveyid;
    this.surveyid = id;
    this.surveyService.getByColumnLimitBy('id', id, 1).subscribe(
      surv => {  surv.map(
        sr => {
          this.survey = sr;
          console.log(sr.title + ' now tit: ' + this.survey.title);
          return;
        });
       });
    this.questionarysService.getByColumn('survey_id', this.surveyid).
       subscribe(dataa => {
          this.questionarys = dataa;
          console.log('length: ' + this.questionarys.length);
          dataa.map( nary => {
                console.log('quetsionary: ' + nary.title + '\n');
                this.questionsServeice.getByColumnLimitByOrderByASC('questionnary_id', nary.id, 1000, 'id').subscribe(
                  question => {
                    question.map( quest => {
                      if (quest.questionnary_id === nary.id) {
                        this.questions.push(quest);
                      }
                      const inputId = quest.input_type_id;
                      let input: any = '';
                      this.inputService.getByColumn('id', inputId).
                    subscribe(inpt => inpt.map(innn => {
                      input = innn.accepted_data;
                    }));
                      this.answerService.getByColumnLimitByOrderByDESC('question_id', quest.id, 5, 'id').
                      subscribe(answerz => {
                      this.questionFullArray.push({question: quest, inputBox: input, answers: answerz});
                      answerz.map(answer => {
                        console.log('answer for ' +
                        quest.id + ' = ' + answer.answer_content );
                        if (quest.questionnary_id === answer.questionary_id
                            && quest.id === answer.question_id && answer.questionary_id === nary.id) {
                          this.answers.push(answer);
                          this.columns.push(quest.question_title);
                          this.rows.push(answer);
                        }
                      });
                    });
                  });
                });
                });
        });
  }

  getQuestions(questionaryId: any) {
    const questions = this.questionFullArray.filter(q => q.question.questionnary_id === questionaryId);
    this.colsize = questions.length;
    return questions;
  }
  getOtherQuestions(questionaryId: any) {
    const questions = this.questionFullArray.filter(
      q => q.question.questionnary_id === questionaryId
      && q.answers.filter(a => a.questionary_id === questionaryId ));
    this.colsize = questions.length;
    return questions;
  }
    getAnswers(questionid: any) {
    const answers = this.answers.filter(anss => anss.question_id === questionid);
    const ans = [];
    answers.forEach(ass => {
      console.log('an :' + ass.answer_content);
     // if (!ans.indexOf(ass.answer_content)) {
      ans.push(ass.answer_content);
        // }
       });
    return ans;
   }
```

these are my services function to get data from firestore they work fine no problem

```
getByColumn(columnname: string, value: any) {
    return this.afs.collection<Questions>('Questions', ref =>
      ref.where(columnname, '==', value))
      .snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          });
        })
      );
  }
  getByColumnLimitByOrderByDESC(columnname: string, value: any,
                                limitby: number, orderby: any) {
    return this.afs.collection<Questions>('Questions', ref =>
    ref.where(columnname, '==', value).limit(limitby).orderBy(orderby, 'desc'))
      .snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data();
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { id, ...data };
      });
      })
    );
  }
  getByColumnLimitByOrderByASC(columnname: string, value: any,
                               limitby: number, orderby: any) {
    return this.afs.collection<Questions>('Questions', ref =>
    ref.where(columnname, '==', value).limit(limitby).orderBy(orderby, 'asc'))
    .snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data();
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
    });
    })
    );
}
```

i hope to get questions as columns and answers in rows and cell.

[this images show what am getting right now as table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p81Px.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your naming conventions are very confusing.

If your data is the wrong way around then have you maybe done this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let answe of getQAnswers(questionary.id)" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<td *ngFor="let answer of getAnswers(answe.question_id); let ii = index"  style="text-align: center;">
```

When you mean this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let answe of getAnswers(questionary.id)" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<td *ngFor="let answer of getQAnswers(answe.question_id); let ii = index"  style="text-align: center;">
```

Or put the wrong query inside the `getAnswers()` and `getQAnswerers()`?